# Differential equation $ x y y' = x^2 + ( 1+ a ) y^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I have to solve this equation, where $ a \in \mathbb R $:
>
> $$ x y y' = x^2 + ( 1+ a ) y^2 $$

And I firstly thought about Bernouilli's method :

we set $ y^2 = z$
then the equation :
$$ x \frac {z'} z = x^2 + (1+a) z $$

so then the homogenous equation gives :
$$\frac{ z' } { z^2 } = \frac{1+a}{x} $$
so $$ \frac 1 z = \ln ( \frac{1}{ x^{1+a}   })+ cst  $$

---

It seems already false comparing to the answer I'm suppose to have. Can you tell me where is my mistake and if the substitution recommanded by Bernouilli's is a good idea?

Comment: If $z=y^2$, then $yy' = \frac{z'}{2}$, not $\frac{z'}{z}.$

Comment: oh thank you ! My bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake with Bernouilli substitution..

$$x y y' = x^2 + ( 1+ a ) y^2$$
$$x\frac 12 (y^2)' = x^2 + ( 1+ a ) y^2$$
Then susbtitute $y^2=z$
$$x\frac 12 z' = x^2 + ( 1+ a )z$$
Which is linear of first order
$$ z' - 2\frac {( 1+ a )}xz= 2x $$

Comment: Thank you ! Can you confirm me that is a good method I choosed ? :) I'm still learning

Comment: yes thats the right method for this kind of equation...you were on the right path just a little mistake with the derivative @MarineGalantin